# Is there a simple method to remove the occurrence of lexeme in a tsvector?

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

I've got a tsvector column in a table and I would like to be able to remove a lexeme from the tsvector.

I've started playing around with ts_stat to rebuild a new tsvector, but it seems quite complicated.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast it to text, remove with regexp, and cast back to tsvector.

Comment: I didn't think the cast was enough. Should have tried...
Thanks

Comment: Note: you have to remove the word as well as the surrounding single quotes, like regexp_replace(vector::text, $$'tobereplaced'$$, '')::tsvector

Comment: I found regexp_replace(vector::text, $$'tobereplaced'\S+ *$$, '', 'g')::tsvector to work

Answer (score 0):

As of Aug 2022 (the moment when this comment was written), you can use `ts_delete()`, which has the below signatures:

```
ts_delete(vector tsvector, lexeme text) → tsvector
ts_delete(vector tsvector, lexemes text[]) → tsvector
```

Example case for a single lexeme:

```
ts_delete('fat:2,4 cat:3 rat:5A'::tsvector, 'fat') → 'cat':3 'rat':5A
```

As seen in the signature, you can also pass an array:

```
ts_delete('fat:2,4 cat:3 rat:5A'::tsvector, ARRAY['fat','rat']) → 'cat':3
```

An interesting use case is subtracting a `tsvector` from another `tsvector`, which can be done by combining `ts_delete()` and `tsvector_to_array()`:

```
ts_delete('fat:2,4 cat:3 rat:5A'::tsvector, tsvector_to_array('cat fat'::tsvector)) → 'rat':5A
```